# How do i set local directory image in leftAvatar of ListItem using react-native-elements?

Tags: react-native, avatar

I am trying to add my local directory image into the leftAvatar but cant achieve it, also there is no such document hint for doing so.Any help would be really appreciated. This is my render method-

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem
              leftAvatar={{
                source: { uri: "../assets/images/classboard.png" },
                showEditButton: false
              }}
              title={`${item.className} ${item.section}`}
              subtitle={item.countStudents.toString()}
              containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 1 }}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.classId.toString()}
          // ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          // ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          // ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          // onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
          // refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          // onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
          // onEndReachedThreshold={50}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use your local resource you can do this:

```
source: require("../assets/images/classboard.png"),
```

Tell me if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the avatar is still not being rendered

Comment: it worked, it was a silly mistake, i didn't restart the server. sorry....n thanks for helping

Comment: for a while there, i was about to question my RN knowledge

Comment: how can i add backgroundColor to the avatar ?

Comment: as I am not familiar with rn-elements, consider reading the documentation of the avatar here: https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/avatar.html#avatar-props it's the same avatar being used in the list and in other locations, check its props

Answer (score 0):

for  **local image**  in react native  avatar use  this

```
<Avatar.Image source={require("../images/a.jpg")} size={50} />
```